# Programmatic introspection/reflection - easier in VMs?

Tags: jvm, vm-implementation

What makes programmatic introspection/reflection easier in virtual machines rather than native code?

I read somewhere that VMs by nature allow for better introspection/reflection capabilities but I cannot find more information about it online. Would like to know why.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean higher-level languages vs lower-level languages instead of virtual machines.

Higher level languages like Java and C# have implemented reflection and introspection, so there are functions available to the developer to use this information.

Languages like C do not have any pre-built reflection capabilities.

Reflection is very expensive (time-consuming) for any language to run, and should not be used in code that needs to be extremely fast.

Comment: no, I did mean VMs, I read somewhere that languages running in a VM have better introspection capabilities by nature, but I can't find any more good information about this online.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic introspection essentially means to examine & inspect the current [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), or the current [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). (Read Appel's book: Compiling with Continuations).

Few programming languages provide this ability. Scheme's [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) reifies the current continuation, but give no standard ways to inspect it.

The current call stack might be inspectable (e.g. see GCC [__builtin_return_address](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) as an ad hoc example).

Most compilers (but not all) do not have an easy way to give information about the layout of the current call frame (however, the debugger [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format contains it).

And optimizing compilers (e.g. for C) usually don't give access to the *offset* of some local variable in the call frame (even if the compiler computes this offset). BTW, the same stack slot might be reused for different variables; read about [register spilling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation#Spilling).

See also J.Pitrat's [CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/04/caia-my-colleague/) system - the generated C code is able to organize the stack to be able to inspect it;

In a bytecode VM like [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) or [NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/) or [Parrot](http://parrot.org/), introspection is easier because each local variable has a well defined slot in the call frame. This is not the case for most compiled languages (e.g. C or C++) because the compiler is able to reuse (for optimization purposes) some slots, or even put a variable only in some machine register, without even allocating any call stack slot to spill it.